# P&T Switch throws an error with EE 2.7.2

Tags: pixelandtonic

I just upgraded to EE 2.7.2 and P&T Switch is throwing an error in the Developer Log. Everything still seems to work at the moment but it looks like P&T Switch needs to be updated:

```
Deprecated function EE_Fieldtype() called in system/expressionengine/third_party/pt_switch/ft.pt_switch.php on line 26. Deprecated since 2.6. Use EE_Fieldtype::__construct() instead.
```

Comment: Which version of the P&T Field Pack do you have installed? The change log notes a few updates for P&T Switch related to method names and PHP errors. [http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/fieldpack/changelog.html](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/fieldpack/changelog.html)

Answer (score 4):

P&T switch has moved into a new bundle of old dive bar addons called [Field Pack](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-pack) as of August 2013. You should update to that and everything will be working fine. Updating is simple, but do read the docs.

http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/fieldpack/installation.html#updating-from-the-old-dive-bar-fieldtypes